# Sqlite Database Error: The FMDatabase <FMDatabase: 0x6080000a96c0> is not open.

Tags: swift, fmdb

I'm getting this Error "The FMDatabase  is not open". Even after i open my database first before executing query. Here's the code of instance of database which i'm using to open database.

```
var instance = ModelManager()

class ModelManager: NSObject {

var database: FMDatabase? = nil
var database2: FMDatabase? = nil
var resultSet: FMResultSet!

class func getInstance(sqllite:String) -> ModelManager {
    if(instance.database == nil){
        instance.database = FMDatabase(path: Util.getPath(sqllite))
    }
    return instance
}
class func getInstance2(sqllite:String) -> ModelManager {
    if(instance.database2 == nil){
        instance.database2 = FMDatabase(path: Util.getPath(sqllite))
    }
    return instance
}
```

}

and this is the the code where i am getting error.

```
   func saveImageAudio(audioFile:String?,imageFile:String?,isImage:Bool){

    guard (instance.database?.open())! else {
        return
    }

    let fileName = isImage == true ? imageFile : audioFile
    var paramName = isImage == true ? "imageList" : "audioList"
    let countParam = isImage == true ? "imageCount" : "audioCount"
    let time = Util.DateTime()

    guard increaseLastNo(isImage: isImage) else {
        return
    }

    do {

        let FileArray = getImageAudiolist(isImagelist: isImage)

        var query = ""
        var values:[Any] = []

        if FileArray.count == 0 {
            query = "update RoomSectionDetails set \(paramName) = ?, \(countParam) = 1 ,modified_dtm = ? where  pda_guid = ? and roomName = ? and sectionID = ? and dead = ?"
            values = [fileName!,time,pda_guid,roomName,sectionId,0]
        }else{
            query = "update RoomSectionDetails set \(paramName) = \(paramName) || ?, \(countParam) = \(countParam) + 1, modified_dtm = ? where  pda_guid = ? and roomName = ? and sectionID = ? and dead = ?"
            values = [",\(fileName!)",time,pda_guid,roomName,sectionId,0]
        }

        try instance.database?.executeUpdate(query, values: values)

        paramName = isImage == true ? "lastImageNo" : "lastAudioNo"

        if !isImage {
            self.updateAudioDuration()
        }
    } catch  {
        print("Error while Saving Image Audio in DB")
    }
     instance.database?.close()
   }
```

Please give the solution for this problem. I wasn't closing database ever time after firing queries. that causes cpu usages more then 200. So now i'm closing database. but i am getting this error. Thanks for Help.

Comment: have you called `getInstance` or `getInstance2` somewhere in your code before calling `saveImageAudio`?

Comment: I would highly recommend to declare `database` and `database2` as *lazy* variables instead of implementing `getInstance` and `getInstance2`

Comment: Yes,Ahmad F. I called in App deletgate.

Comment: But declaring lazy won't be solve issue of this error. i already tried that.

Answer (score 2):

I found the Solution for this problem. I am having method inside method which closing the database. Because of that error coming. Thanks for help.